# How can I view javascript errors when running in Headless chrome on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

Some of the javascript isn't loading on my pages during Rails system tests. I have no idea why so I need access to the javascript errors.

How can I get `rails test:system` to show javascript errors?

I currently have this in `application_system_test_case.rb`:

```
   driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400]
```

Comment: for testing on development system, you can set the driver to just `chrome` instead of `headless_chrome` and you can view the js error in the chrome devtools

Comment: Have you tried adding `loggingPrefs` arg with `{'browser':'ALL'}`? This should give you the access to the browser logs with `driver.get_log('browser')` FYI the driver call is python reference.

Comment: Having the same issue - somehow my tests pass on my dev machine in headless and non-headless but fail (apparently not executing my JS) in CI using headless (note: I'm using FF but not sure if that's important)